# Toast Message from Custom Image View

Tags: android, imageview, toast

How can I display a toast message from within a class which extends ImageView.  I'd like to place it in the onDoubleTap method so it displays a message to the user as to what pixel was just double tapped.  I have the following two classes:

```
public class TouchImageView extends ImageView 
{
  ....
   final GestureDetector mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) 
        {           
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pixel",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return true;
        }
        ...
   }

public class DisplayMap extends Activity 
{
  int width;
  int height;
  double imageSize;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TouchImageView img = new TouchImageView(getApplicationContext());

    Bitmap mapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.testimage);
    img.setImageBitmap(mapImage);
    img.setMaxZoom(4f);
    setContentView(img);
    ...
}
```

The code above won't work because 
    getApplicationContext() is undefined for ImageView.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your `TouchImageView` class a constructor that accepts a `Context` object.

```
Context context;

public TouchImageView(Context context) {
    super(context); //Thanks for this tip
    this.context = context;      
}

final GestureDetector mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() 
{
    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) 
    {           
        Toast.makeText(context, "Pixel",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return true;
    }
    ...
}
```

And send your Activity.this object in the TouchImageView object

Answer (score 0):

If you are subclassing ImageView, the method getContext() will be inherited. Use this to show your Toast.

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Pixel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

To clarify the other answer, if you are subclassing ImageView just call super(context); Don't worry about maintaining your own context instance.

This:

```
 Context context;

public TouchImageView(Context context) {
    this.context = context;      
}
```

Should be:

```
Context context; // <-- remove this

public TouchImageView(Context context) {
     super(context);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: To jump in on your answer, josh, you can't call `getContext()` because that line is in the Anonymous Class and not the `TouchImageView` class.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext()  getContext is a view method, image view extends View, and this fellow is extending ImageView so the call for getting the context should be there

Comment: I did not try this yet but will.  Thanks everyone